# How to avoid repeated similar "mapping class=repeated.package.declaration.UniqueClass" in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration

In `hibernate.cfg.xml` I wrote following rows:

```
<mapping class="com.company.our_project_name.model.User" />
```

I have a lot of same rows.

I want to replace all these rows by one like this:

```
    <mapping package="com.company.our_project_name.model" />
```

But after it I see

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.company.our_project_name.model.User
```

How to resolve my problem?

Comment: can you show us `model.User` class?

Comment: it is usual class with two fields - id and name